# php generated semicolon delimited csv showing all values in one column

Tags: php, csv, fputcsv

I want to use different delimiters while generating CSV. When I try comma then it works fine means all values show in different columns but when I try other delimiters like ; or | then it shows all values in one column. Following code is showing all column's data in one column.

```
$csv_filename = $this->saveFileToDirectory.$this->fileName;
$fp = fopen ($csv_filename, "w");
fputcsv($fp, $this->headerArr);
foreach ($this->data as $key => $value) {
    if(is_array($value)) {
        $csvData = $this->makeStringFromArr($value);
        fputcsv($fp, explode(";",$csvData),";");
    }
}
fclose($fp);
```

$csvData value is following

> "GUARANTEED AVAILABILITY;GUARANTEED AVAILABILITY;GUARANTEED
>   AVAILABILITY;;my;GUARANTEED AVAILABILITY
>   ;34.5;;BLUE;80463259;VERY_GOOD;H1078;N;sss;dummy value;GUARANTEED
>   AVAILABILITY;"14.50, 34.50&Acirc ;°, ";GUARANTEED
>   AVAILABILITY;sdf"

If I replace following line then it does not show data in CSV

```
fputcsv($fp, $csvData,';');
```

Following is sample CSV

[image]

Any suggestion? What I am doing wrong or it is right and will be visible in one column when exported with other delimiters than comma?

Comment: Can you show the file contents it's creating (or at least the first few lines)

Comment: First line contain column names

Comment: You seem to have quotes `"` all over the place, take the first data row - starts with a quote then some text and then a ';'.  Either remove them all or let the `fputcsv` add them using the enclosure parameter.

Comment: I have edited question and added sample text in it and one code line was missing. I have added that as well.

Comment: @NigelRen Even I tried to put static value like fputcsv($fp, array('abc','bcd','cde','efg','ghi','ijk'),';'); but it gives same problem

Comment: OK - I notice that the header is written without the ';' option, so it's being written as a comma separated list.  Next is to look at the raw file, opening it as a spreadsheet MAY not recognise the ';'s  it may default to ',', so check the raw data.

Comment: @NigelRen I have removed header and tried static data. raw data was abc;bcd;cde;efg;igh
abc;bcd;cde;efg;igh
abc;bcd;cde;efg;igh

But still showing incorrect means in one column

Comment: So this is working then, add your header back in (remember to add ';' option), check how your viewing the data (Excel?) and ensure you say your separator is ';'.

Comment: @NigelRen Now all data is showing in one column, I think, it should come in separate column

Answer (score -1):

Try this Code...

```
$file_handle = fopen('/var/www/demo.csv', 'w');

// save header for csv | if you want title for your column
// $header_title = ['column_1', 'column_2'];
// fputs($file_handle, implode(",", array_map("encodeFunc", $header_title)) . "\r\n");


$csv_data = ["valu1", "value12"];
fputs($file_handle, implode(",", array_map("encodeFunc", $csv_data)) . "\r\n");
fclose($file_handle);


function encodeFunc($value) {
    ///remove any ESCAPED double quotes within string.
    $value = str_replace('\\"', '', $value);

    //then force escape these same double quotes And Any UNESCAPED Ones.
    $value = str_replace('"', '', $value);

  //force wrap value in quotes and return
    return '"' . $value . '"';
}
```

Comment: Let me know whats wrong in this code....? so i can improve it..... it works fine for me.